# Reading long register data from an I2C bus of a microcontroller

Tags: c, iot, microcontroller, i2c

I'm trying to connect a BME280 temperature sensor to an A9G microcontroller with custom firmware. Both devices support the I2C protocol and I have found the developer's library for the sensor. The only problem is, I can't seem to implement the callbacks that the library requires correctly with the A9G I2C API.

The library wants 3 function callbacks - for reading, writing and waiting.
The OS has these functions for reading and writing on the I2C bus: [I2C Reference](https://ai-thinker-open.github.io/GPRS_C_SDK_DOC/en/c-sdk/function-api/iic.html).

I tried to implement the write like this:

```
int8_t Bme280_I2C_Write(uint_8t, reg_addr, const uint8_t* data,
                        uint32_t len, uint8_t address)
{
    I2C_Error_t res = I2C_WriteMem(I2C2, address, reg_addr, len,
                                   (uint8_t*)data, len, I2C_DEFAULT_TIME_OUT);
    return res != I2C_ERROR_NONE;
}
```

And it seems to work fine. I also implemented the read function in a similar way - using `I2C_ReadMem`, and it works for reading up to 4 bytes from a register. **But the docs say `I2C_ReadMem` can only read up to 4 bytes and the library wants to read >20 bytes at a time.**

There are functions like I2C_WriteRawByte, I2C_ReadRawByte, I2C_Receive and I tried to implement the I2C protocol with them but I keep getting errors like LINE_BUSY and reading only 0xFF. I don't know exactly what the functions combined with the command parameters do, which adds to the confusion. For example, if I send an I2C_CMD_MASK_MASTER_START, I'm also supposed to give a byte to send. But what should that byte be? Here's one of my attempts (error handling omitted for clarity):

```
int8_t Bme280_I2C_Read(uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t* data, uint32_t len, void* intf_ptr)
{
    Bme280* pThis = intf_ptr;

    I2C_Error_t result;

    if (len <= 4)
    {
        // This works.
        I2C_ReadMem(pThis->i2c, pThis->address, reg_addr, len,
                    data, len, I2C_DEFAULT_TIME_OUT);
        return 0;
    }

    // START
    I2C_WriteRawByte(pThis->i2c, pThis->address,
                     I2C_CMD_MASK_MASTER_START, I2C_DEFAULT_TIME_OUT);

    // ADDRESS + W
    I2C_WriteRawByte(pThis->i2c, pThis->address,
                     I2C_CMD_MASK_MASTER_WRITE, I2C_DEFAULT_TIME_OUT);

    // REGISTER
    I2C_WriteRawByte(pThis->i2c, reg_addr,
                     I2C_CMD_MASK_MASTER_WRITE, I2C_DEFAULT_TIME_OUT);

    // RESTART
    I2C_WriteRawByte(pThis->i2c, pThis->address,
                     I2C_CMD_MASK_MASTER_START, I2C_DEFAULT_TIME_OUT);

    // ADDRESS + R
    I2C_WriteRawByte(pThis->i2c, pThis->address,
                     I2C_CMD_MASK_MASTER_READ, I2C_DEFAULT_TIME_OUT);

    // READ
    result = I2C_Receive(pThis->i2c, pThis->address,
                         data, len, I2C_DEFAULT_TIME_OUT);
    /*uint32_t read = 0;
    while(read++ < len)
    {
        *data = I2C_ReadRawByte(pThis->i2c, I2C_CMD_MASK_MASTER_READ,
                                I2C_DEFAULT_TIME_OUT);
        I2C_WriteRawByte(pThis->i2c, pThis->address,
                         I2C_CMD_MASK_MASTER_NACK, I2C_DEFAULT_TIME_OUT);
        data++;
    }*/
    

    // STOP
    I2C_WriteRawByte(pThis->i2c, pThis->address,
                     I2C_CMD_MASK_MASTER_STOP, I2C_DEFAULT_TIME_OUT);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think your interpretation (re. 4 byte max for `I2C_ReadMem`) is incorrect. That's _not_ total/data length. That's what the `length` parameter is for. It's: _memSize：slave register **address** length,unit:byte, max 4_ `I2C_WriteMem` has the same issue, but it's working.

Comment: Oh, wow. I can't believe I missed that. I thought the second length was for some "3 bytes in a 4 byte variable" magic. I made the length of the register address 1 byte and everything worked. Thanks!

Comment: The docs are [sparse] ;-) The arg is: `...,uint16_t slaveAddr, uint32_t memAddr,uint8_t memSize,...` and `memSize` refers to `memAddr`. Note that `slaveAddr` is the _slave address_. But, `memAddr` is the _slave **register** address_. I've forgotten most of my I2C, but, I'll hazard a guess. `slaveAddress` is the I2C bus address of the device. And, `memAddr` is the address [i.e. offset] of a given data register _within_ that device.

Comment: Some I2C devices could have (e.g.) 7 registers--so `memSize` of 1. Some devices might have 32000 registers, so `memSize` of 2. Some devices could map huge amounts of DRAM, (e.g.) 16MB, so `memSize` of 3.

Comment: You are absolutely right!